# Mysterious Clock - Windows XP

Tags: windows-xp, virus, clock

User showed me this clock on the screen today - its modal but fixed on top.  Anti-virus revealed nothing - and no shifty programs or services to my eye are running.
[image]

Hopefully AV deep scan will reveal something?

Comment: Did you figure out what it was?

Comment: Is it static or dynamic? i.e. does it indicate the true time, or is it stuck on 10:39?

Comment: would be nice to know what this was.

Comment: @Michael - yes it was malware posing as a JPG in the sysroot32 folder.

Comment: @dev - dynamic clock

Comment: @diskilla - see response to Michael

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Download Process Explorer from http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx

& then use the 'Find Window's Process' Tool to find what process is running it. You can then google for the process to find if it might be a virus or a prank.

Answer (score 0):

Look for malware file %sysroot32%\DSC03001.exe. Masquerades as a jpg